# Partial path known..need to search for file type inside

Tags: batch-file

There is a particular folder that begins with a name such as SS followed by random characters. The names would be different every time and the only thing we are sure of is the folder begins with SS. How do we look if this folder has a .txt file inside in batch programming.

Comment: Did one of the solutions work for you?

Answer (score 0):

An idea :

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b/ad ^|find /i "SS"') do set $Dir=%%a
dir /b/a-d *.txt %$dir%>nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 echo File(s) found in "%$DIR%"
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%\ss*" 2^>nul'
  ) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%h IN (
   'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\%%a\*.txt" 2^>nul'
   ) DO (
  ECHO "%sourcedir%\%%a\%%h"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

should solve your problem - you need to change `sourcedir` to suit your system, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

The code below check if the folder contain *any* .txt file:

```
@echo off

set "filePath="
for /D %%a in (SS*) do if exist "%%a\*.txt" do set "filePath=%%a"
if defined filePath echo File exists in folder %filePath%
```

If you want to check for a *particular* .txt file, just change `*.txt` by the appropriate name.